# Install APK in Blackberry 10: Unable to install this app

Tags: android, cordova, blackberry, apk, blackberry-10

I've build a sample android app with phonegap 2.9.0 tried to install the apk in blackberry Q10 (10.2.1.1925)
But I get the following message:  Unable to install this app

I've also tried running a plain android hello world app and still got the same message.
Funny thing is that other apps seem to install correctly.

I read somewhere that you have first to execute an android app and the install your apk.
I tried that it didn't work either..

Comment: I thought with PhoneGap, you would build a BB version, rather than attempting to port the Android build. But probably I am missing something, since I don't know PhoneGap.

Comment: Yes I could build a BB version, but it's a lot easier to just run the apk.

Comment: What do you mean other apps seem to install correctly?

Comment: The user has installed and run android apps already in his phone.

Comment: Using a .apk file to install, or downloading it through some official store?

Comment: Using an .apk file to install.

Comment: They need to be signed.

Comment: Can you pls provide a link, if i google this it appears that you just create the apk, and that's it, (for Q10), but i can't find a resource related to the signing of the apk that you mention

Comment: http://techdominators.com/how-to-install-android-apk-files-on-blackberry-os-10-2-1-1055/

Comment: Thanks, I can install apks from the amazon app store, the question is why a simple hello world apk i created does not install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link signing your apk, creating release storekey to be able to install your apk into blackberry 10 :http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: This has worked for me in the past, but not working now.  Even after I sign I still get the error on my Q10...

Answer (score 2):

Bojan Kogoj is correct and thanks to him. For whatever reason, I signed it and it now works perfectly in my Q10. Hope it works with you too!

Comment: Seems more a comment than an answer

Comment: @GoodGov Thanks a lot for your answer, can you provide a link with the steps you followed? So you converted the app to a bar?

Answer (score 0):

try using the command line tool for converting apk to bar file..
there 2 version of cmd tool .. latest 2.0 seems to have a gui interface..

Comment: The apk works great, just needs to be signed, it's far easier.